# How to Convert a String Column to Decimal Column using Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with a string column that I need to convert to decimal. Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

I have attempted the following:

```
df_line_items = df_line_items.withColumn("product_sold_price", df_line_items.product_sold_price.cast("decimal(3,2)"))
```

, but it just made all the values null. Grateful for any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using decimal, try using Double - that should solve all your problems.

df_line_items = df_line_items.withColumn("product_sold_price", df_line_items.product_sold_price.cast("double"))

Comment: thanks. This worked except that I needed to the schema to show as a decimal table. Thanks. I agree your solution works though.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `decimal(3,2)` can only allow 3 digits of precision and 2 digits behind the decimal point (range -9.99 to 9.99) while your data are beyond that range. From the image above, at least you need to cast them to `decimal(5,2)`.